# jquery not working while implemented in html header of Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use jquery in my pages on a wordpress install, and nothing seems to work.
it is called via php line (if i got it right) :

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

I am assuming some jquery scripts are working (the ones coming together with the theme i'm using) but for some reason no single other script that i'd like to add will function. 
I tried implementing it/them in the header of my index page, or in a js file, but none of these methods seem to work. 
here is the link : http://selectedworx.com

thank you for any hint on how to get it working... it's driving me nuts :/

Comment: `$` is undefined.. try using `jQuery` instead of `$` place or reassign it back to jQuery `$=jQuery` since it doesn't look anything else is using it because it's undefined

Comment: The example page used is loading jquery just fine, do what @wirey said

Comment: Try, just as `wirey` said, `$` to `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<?php wp_head();?>` inside your header and inside your footer `<?php wp_footer();?>` Also add no-conflict mode for your Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    alert('This is a alert!!');
    //So now you can call your functions with $ !
            $('.someclass').hide();//for example    
    });
```

Comment: thank you guys for your answers.. i found a solution here : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/include-jquery-in-headerphp-please-help

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7uAUg/
Your code seems to be working fine, the $ operator is likely being assigned to a different meaning.  This is likely happening in one of the 40+ includes that happen in your page.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

is the only exception you are experiencing so instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                          
     $("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
</script>
```

use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                          
     jQuery("div").css("border", "3px solid red");
});
</script>
```

as stated by @wirey

Comment: yes ! that was it. the easy solution is to use this portion of code : jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 //code.
});
and put what you need inside. thank you guys for your reactivity...